# MySQL 5.5 not shutting down on mac

Tags: mysql

I have a problem shutting down the mysql server that is running on my mac. I tried from ActivityMonitor, from terminal using "mysqladmin shutdown" , kill -9 , and many other proposed ways but it always restarts within a second. Error log doesnt show anything strange:

```
    30113 16:28:12 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130113 16:28:12 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130113 16:28:14 [Warning] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 3  user: 'root'

130113 16:28:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130113 16:28:15  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2614644
130113 16:28:15 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130113 16:28:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/mun07066.local.pid ended
130113 16:28:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
130113 16:28:15 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
130113 16:28:15 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130113 16:28:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130113 16:28:16  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130113 16:28:17 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 2614644
130113 16:28:17 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130113 16:28:17 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130113 16:28:17 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130113 16:28:17 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130113 16:28:17 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25a/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.25a'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Comment: Perhaps reboot your machine. Then System Preferences --> MySql --> Stop MySql Server

Comment: No this doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Same problem, 2-1/2 years on, with MySQL 5.6.26 installed via Homebrew on OS X El Capitan. Nothing works; not the system-preferences panel, not `kill -9`, *nothing*. It's chewing up half a gig of RAM, doing nothing.